# Validation of an API in codeigniter not working properly

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

I am writing an API in codeigniter. I am validating the fields it has with codeigniter built in function but somehow it's not working as it should.

```
public function check_validation()
{

     $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
     $this->load->library('form_validation');


     $firstname     = mysql_real_escape_string($this->input->post('firstname'));
    $lastname   = mysql_real_escape_string($this->input->post('lastname'));
    $email  = mysql_real_escape_string($this->input->post('email'));*/


     //$firstname = 'Numaan';
     //$lastname = 'sheikh';
     //$email = 'test@test.com';


    $this->form_validation->set_rules('firstname', 'Username', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required');


    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
                $finalResult = array('code' => 100,
                'msg'=>'Field Emsdsdspty.',
                'data' => array()
                );
        }
        else
        {
                $finalResult = array('code' => 100,
                'msg'=>'Validation Successful.',
                'data' => array()
                );
        }

    echo json_encode($finalResult);

}
```

I am trying to get the posted values but it is not working properly.then i also tried to assign the values to the variables and then passed through the  validation it also did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (i not testing)

```
function check_validation()
{

    $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    //default result
    $finalResult = array('code' => 500, 'msg' => 'Unknow Error', 'data' => array());

    if($this->input->post()) {
        //set validaton
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('firstname', 'Username', 'trim|strip_tags|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('lastname', 'Lastname', 'trim|strip_tags|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'trim|strip_tags|required');

        //check form
        if($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE) {
            $finalResult = array('code' => 200, 'msg' => 'Success', 'data' => array()); 
        }else {
            $finalResult = array('code' => 400, 'msg' => validation_errors(), 'data' => array());
        }
    }

    echo json_encode($finalResult);
}
```

ps. api status code: http://www.restapitutorial.com/httpstatuscodes.html